# Setting default user in user table

Tags: sql, default-value, ssms, referential-integrity

I'm working on a database and I have a table called "Users", which store the sites user information (username, email and so on). The site has a forum and if a user that has posted something on the site deletes his account, I want "Deleted user" to appear instead of the username next to the post.

I know this is possible to do with referential integrity (set default) in SQL Management Studio, but I just can't figure out how to do it. I have created a user in the table called "Deleted user" that has got UserId "1".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not add flag to user table `deleted` set it to true/false and when querying user you can use `case when deleted = 1 then 'Deleted User' Else UserName End UserName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be up to the database to determine what a default user is or how to handle the logic around a delete.  The application should say to the database, "give me user 123" and the database should say return no result or a flag saying that the user is deleted.  The app would then take that information and display "Deleted user".  Logic like that should be abstracted away from the data.